# Iterating over an HTMLCollection in a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to write a Chrome extension that modifies the appearance of tweets on Twitter.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', myMain, false)

function myMain() {
  console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('article'))
  console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('article').length)
  for (const article of document.getElementsByTagName('article')) {
    console.log('print something if this code is ever reached')
    console.log(article)
  }
}
```

Produces the following output:
[image]

Hence `console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('article'))` retrieves every articles element, but the HTMLCollection CANNOT be iterated over.

I have seen other StackOverflow threads that suggest that the script must run after the page has loaded (e.g.: [Iterate over HTMLCollection in custom element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53135217/iterate-over-htmlcollection-in-custom-element), [HTMLCollection appearing in console with many elements but has length 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46554004/htmlcollection-appearing-in-console-with-many-elements-but-has-length-0)). But Twitter seems to be forever loading, so that solution does not work here. Is there any way to retrieve the content of `document.getElementsByTagName('article')` given that the Javascript is clearly retrieving ***something*** in order to be able to print it to the console?

Comment: "*`console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('article'))` retrieves every articles element*" - no it doesn't, see [Is Chrome's JavaScript console lazy about evaluating arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4057440/1048572). As you can see, when the code runs the list has length 0. The answers on the questions you found are accurate.

Comment: "*But Twitter seems to be forever loading*" - they're probably loading the elements lazily using js, so they don't exist on `DOMContentLoaded` either. You can use a mutation observer to recognise them being added to the DOM. What's the [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) you're trying to solve?

Comment: @Bergi I stated the actual problem I'm trying to solve in the first sentence of this question: "modify the appearance of tweets on Twitter." More specifically, for each Tweet, add a new button to the Tweet. Mutation Observer may be my best bet.

Comment: Ah right. Neither CSS nor event delegation will help you to add a button. (Or, they might, but mutation observer is probably simpler)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that HTMLCollection does not behave completely like an Array, which means that doing:

```js
for (const element of HTMLCollection){
  console.log(element)
}
```

Does not actually return element of that collection, but the HTMLCollection itself. To get to the element, you need to do any flavor of following:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < HTMLCollection.length; i++) {
  console.log(HTMLCollection[i]);
}
```

In other words you need to address element by it's index.